# unable to set matplotlib figure facecolor to none

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, matplotlib, pygtk

As per matplotlib documentation, I am trying to set transparent background to figure and subplot using patch.set_facecolor('none')

It is working for subplot but not for figure.

```
def create_plot_win(self,label_list,set_prop=1,box=None): 
    ax_list=[]
    fig1 = Figure(tight_layout=True)
    fig1.patch.set_facecolor('none')
    l=len(label_list)
    for i in range(len(label_list)):
        ax_list.append(fig1.add_subplot(l,1,i+1))
        ax_list[-1].patch.set_facecolor('none')
    canvas = FigureCanvas(fig1) 
    toolbar=NavigationToolbar(canvas,box)
    box.pack_start(toolbar,False,False,0)
    if l ==1:return canvas,fig1,toolbar,ax_list[0]
```

How can I set figure background as transparent?

I am working on windows-8.1 with python-2.7.

if i set figure facecolor to 'none', i am getting figure with a black background and my application background is having image.

For screen shot, click here [screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3S1H1.png)

```
import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('GtkAgg')
from matplotlib.backends.backend_gtkagg import FigureCanvasGTKAgg as    Canvas
import pylab
import cairo
class PyApp(gtk.Window):
   def __init__(self):
       super(PyApp, self).__init__()
       self.set_position(gtk.WIN_POS_CENTER)
       self.fig = matplotlib.pyplot.figure()
       self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)     
       self.canvas = Canvas(self.fig)
       self.ax.plot([0,1,2,3,4],[0,1,4,9,16])
       self.ax.patch.set_facecolor('none')
       self.fig.patch.set_facecolor('none')    
       self.pltbox = gtk.VBox(False, 0)
       self.pltbox.pack_start(self.canvas)
       self.add(self.pltbox)
       self.connect("destroy",gtk.main_quit)
       self.show_all()

PyApp()
gtk.main()
```

Comment: link to screen shot added at the end of my post. plz check.

Comment: i am using pygtk for UI. subplot is transparent. I did some sample prog. If I add figure to canvas and pack it in any container widget, i am facing this issue. Its working with plt.show()

Comment: I have added sample code giving same output. please suggest solution.

Comment: Great. I am not an expert in pygtk, but with this minimal example, I'm sure someone will be able to help you.